# Hibernate Criteria runtime class

Tags: hibernate, criteria

This is my hierarchy:

```
// Table a
class A {}

// Table(" b
class B extends A {}

// Table my_class
class MyClass {

    A a;
}
```

I want to retrieve all `MyClass` objects from database with a relation to `B` but not to `A`.

`B` is a `joined-subclass` (extension of the table `a` by id).

My idea was something :

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(MyClass.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("a.class", B.class);
```

But it outputs an error:

```
could not resolve property: a.class of a.b.MyClass
```

This is the simplest way I could put it. Bear in mind that the query is a bit more complicated.

Regards.

Udo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually write a DetachedCriteria which selects all B's and filter MyClass where A in AllBs:

```
DetachedCriteria allBs = DetachedCriteria
  .forClass(B.class)
  .setProjection( Projections.property("id") );

Criteria  criteria = session.createCriteria(MyClass.class)
  .add(Subqueries.In("a", allBs);
```

(There may be errors, I'm not a java programmer.)

Creates something like:

```
select ...
from MyClass
where A in (select id from A inner join B on ...)
```

Comment: +1 I like the idea. I know you are not a java developer but it says that I cannot cast String to Integer. Any idea? Thank you for your time

Comment: "A" should be "a". Thank you.